# Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit doesn't work on a win7 with check point full disk encryption

Tags: wubi, windows-7, encryption

I installed 12.04 64bit with the WUBI installer on a Windows 7 with **Check Point Full Disk Encryption**.

The WUBI Installer runs without any trouble selecting the compatibility mode with Windows XP and as Administrator.

The problem is that after the installation is complete and the reboot done, when you restart the system, there's no option to start Ubuntu instead of Windows.

I recently installed Ubuntu on other Windows 7 machines without any problem. But those laptops don't have the Check Point Full Disk Encryption. And when you restart the system you have the option to start in Ubuntu.

If somebody has resolved this issue please share.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, your boot options are encrypted, as well as the Ubuntu installation image and hard disk images.  Even if you managed to make the boot options visible **it would not be possible to boot/install Ubuntu** because you are using an unsupported full-disk encryption scheme.  If this were even supported in userspace, it would still not work because the initramfs image used to boot Ubuntu uses `ntfs-3g`, which cannot decrypt your files.

The only way to install Ubuntu on your computer is to use a virtual machine or repartition your hard drive.